# Recommendations for short film script

Tags: screenwriting, scriptwriting, contests

I would like to take a part in screenplay competition. 
The main goal is a script for a short film (8 - 10 minutes).

I have several questions about it:

1. How long should the script be?
2. How many elements it should consist of? (It is a writer's competition, so, the director(s) will ask the writer details if necessary, not sure).
3. Are there any examples of scripts of this length of short films?
4. Should I worry about time metrics at the end of editing? (Dialogs could take a lot of time, for example, while action scenes are very quick).

Comment: This might be a little too broad, as you're asking four questions at once. Feel free to break this up into multiple posts.

Comment: The rule of thumb is that 1 page of script equals 1 minute of screentime - a little less for dialog scenes, a little more for action scenes.

Comment: @F1Krazy could you advise a separation of this question? I could split it into two ( examples and duration ), maybe one more question about details ( should I worry about them )

Comment: Yeah, this is really way too broad.  #1 is a fine question, but has probably been asked here (check).  #2 depends on the contest guidelines, which you might want to put a link to.  If the guidelines aren't clear, it makes a good question.  #3 is off topic for here.  #4 can be folded into #1 and I'll say that's why they gave you a range.

Comment: I edited your question for tags and content, but I still say it's too broad and I would like to see you ask part of the question (say #1 + #4, if not a duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

There is a very strict standard format for screenplays, designed so that each written page of the script will take approximately 1 minute of screen time. The formatting is different for action and dialog in order to maintain the page/time ratio no matter what the content.  So, if you follow the format, a script for an 8 minute movie will "magically" be 8 pages long.

https://screenwriting.io/what-is-standard-screenplay-format/

This is not long, so your story should probably be simple and to-the-point rather than detailed and complex.  The following link is to a site that posts examples of scripts for short films:

http://www.simplyscripts.com/original-short-scripts.html